# Android studio ,xml design, layout design

Tags: xml, android-studio

I want to design a page in Android studio 2.2.3 i need to design a button with icon or image and text give me some ideas plz , thank you.
That not to need button the image and text have to place in a single surface and have click that they need to act like a button thank you

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try creating some layout (eg. LinearLayout or RelativeLayout) and adding the image and the text inside it. Then, you can set an OnClickListener for the layout and detect button clicks.